# Python list passing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating a black jack game using python.  I have done a lot of reading around local variables, passing, returning, but I am quite confused as to why the print statement in my main() function works the way it is below, but when I change it to

```
print "The playerCards are: ", returned_playerCards
```

it prints 'None' if I had 'hit' for another card in my other functions.
Is the playerCards list global somehow?  What is happening when I call my playerDecision function which then calls the playerHit function which then calls the playerDecision function.  Just typing all of that out makes me think it is the wrong way of doing this.  How else would I do it?

```
from random import randint
import time
A = 11
J = 10
Q = 10
K = 10
cards = [A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K]

def deal():     
    #playerCards = [cards[randint(0,len(cards)-1)],cards[randint(0,len(cards)-1)]]
    playerCards = [2,3]
    dealerCards = [cards[randint(0,len(cards)-1)],cards[randint(0,len(cards)-1)]]
    print "You have been dealt a ", playerCards[0], "and a ", playerCards[1]
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print "Dealer is showing ", dealerCards[0]
    time.sleep(1)
    return(playerCards, dealerCards)


def playerDecision(playerCards):
    stayhit = raw_input("Would you like to 'stay' or 'hit' >> ")
    if stayhit == 'hit':
        playerCards = playerHit(playerCards)
    elif stayhit == 'stay':
        print "playerCards in elif of playerDecision ", playerCards
        return(playerCards)
    return(playerCards)

def playerHit(playerCards):
    playerCards.insert(0, cards[randint(0,len(cards)-1)])
    print "You were dealt a  ", playerCards[0]
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print "Your current total is ", sum(playerCards)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    if sum(playerCards) > 21:
        return(playerCards)
    else:
        print "PlayerCards in else of playerHit are ", playerCards
        playerDecision(playerCards)

def main():
    playerCards, dealerCards = deal()
    returned_playerCards = playerDecision(playerCards)      
    print "The player cards are:  ", playerCards

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, where you have

```
    else:
        print "PlayerCards in else of playerHit are ", playerCards
        playerDecision(playerCards)
```

you need a `return`:

```
    else:
        print "PlayerCards in else of playerHit are ", playerCards
        return playerDecision(playerCards)
```

otherwise the function ends without a `return` statement, which is the equivalent of `return None`.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't realize you could do that Hugh.  So I made your recommended change and it worked.  I thought that the return would have   jumped the code back into the playerDecision function at the point from which it left (where I called the playerHit function), but it didn't.  It started the function from the top.  Why is that?